# postgresql rule to trigger

Tags: postgis, postgresql, trigger

I have two spatial tables and I am mirroring the data between the two table with a postgres rule:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE RULE create_centroid AS ON INSERT TO csg.client_area_request DO INSERT INTO csg.stats (date_needed, date_requested, notice_period, project_name, project_reference, the_geom_webmercator) VALUES (new.date_needed, new.date_requested, new.notice_period, new.project_name, new.project_reference, st_centroid(new.the_geom_webmercator));
```

Is there any way to do the same process with trigger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the procedural function as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE create_centroid()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS 
$body$
BEGIN
        INSERT INTO csg.stats (date_needed, date_requested, notice_period, project_name, project_reference, the_geom_webmercator) VALUES (NEW.date_needed, NEW.date_requested, NEW.notice_period, NEW.project_name, NEW.project_reference, st_centroid(NEW.the_geom_webmercator));
        RAISE NOTICE 'Inserted';
        RETURN null;
END
$body$ language plpgsql volatile;
```

and create trigger (as was explained by the @zimmi) as

```
CREATE TRIGGER create_centroid AFTER INSERT ON csg.client_area_request
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE create_centroid();
```

I was using this trigger to `update` the stats table. Should work.

Comment: I got an error on this. I can save it if I change to "create or replace function..." But when I add a new line to my table the trigger generate an error: "infinite recursion detected in rules for relation"

Comment: I think both triggers are good. I tested my personal postgres db and there they just work fine (with some changes) but somehow they don't work in cartodb...

Comment: @TamasKosa Sorry, but I have tested for postgres db only. You should instead change the question to mention cartodb.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_centroid() RETURNS TRIGGER
$$
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO csg.stats (date_needed, date_requested, notice_period, project_name, project_reference, the_geom_webmercator) VALUES (NEW.date_needed, NEW.date_requested, NEW.notice_period, NEW.project_name, NEW.project_reference, st_centroid(NEW.the_geom_webmercator));
  END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER create_centroid AFTER INSERT ON csg.client_area_request
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE create_centroid();
```

should work just fine (not tested though)

Comment: I got an error on this. I don't know where is the mistake

Comment: I think both triggers are good. I tested my personal postgres db and there they just work fine (with some changes) but somehow they don't work in cartodb...

Comment: I thought you were asking for postgresql solution (according to tags of this question).